# Not being able to pre-select desired radio box by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I am trying to pre-select premium delivery by default. I was looking on the web and really don't understand why it would not pre-select the second radio-box. Please find link to [my JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cu65zg3k/7/)

My code is also:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  waitForDelayedContent('#checkout-shipping-method-load .input-checkout-radio .method-title:contains(Take it to my room)', function() {
    jQuery('#checkout-shipping-method-load .input-checkout-radio:not(.mtC) .method-title:contains(Take it to my room)').click();
    jQuery('#checkout-shipping-method-load .input-checkout-radio:not(.mtC):has(.method-title:contains(Take it to my room)) .radio').click();
    jQuery('#checkout-shipping-method-load .input-checkout-radio:has(.method-title:contains(Take it to my room))').addClass('mtC');


  });
});
```

```html
<div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
  <div class="sp-methods">
    <h3 class="title">Delivery Option</h3>
    <p>You must select a delivery option.</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="delivery-method">
        <div class="input-checkout-radio">
          <input checked="checked" class="input-radio" id="s_method_standard" name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="paragon_customrate_standard">
          <label class="radio-label" for="s_method_standard"><span class="radio"></span>  <span class="method-title">FREE Take it to
                    my door</span>
          </label>
        </div>

      </li>
      <li class="delivery-method">
        <div class="input-checkout-radio">
          <input class="input-radio" id="s_method_premium" name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="paragon_customrate_premium">
          <label class="radio-label" for="s_method_premium"><span class="radio"></span>  <span class="method-title"><span class=
                    "price"><span class="currency">£</span>39</span>Take it to my room</span>
          </label>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the first radio box has `checked="check"`. Move that to the second radio box to make it work. No need for JavaScript. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n5h65n73/

Or, if you really need to do it with JavaScript:

```
$("#s_method_premium").prop("checked", true)
```

Comment: The problem is that this is Magento code and I can not modify the checked="check". Can this be done through the jQuery?

Comment: Yes: `$("#s_method_premium").prop("checked", true)`

Comment: No luck with that either. It comes back with an error: VM755:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of null

Comment: My code does work on desktop devices but it does not work on mobile ones

Answer (score 0):

The issue is within your HTML. You have the `checked="checked"` attribute set on the first radio input. So if you remove that attribute and move it to the second one, it'll work as you want.

```html
<div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
    <div class="sp-methods">
        <h3 class="title">Delivery Option</h3>
        <p>You must select a delivery option.</p>
        <ul>
            <li class="delivery-method">
                <div class="input-checkout-radio">
                    <input class="input-radio" id="s_method_standard" name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="paragon_customrate_standard">
                    <label class="radio-label" for="s_method_standard"><span class="radio"></span> <span class="method-title">FREE Take it to
                    my door</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="delivery-method">
                <div class="input-checkout-radio">
                    <input checked class="input-radio" id="s_method_premium" name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="paragon_customrate_premium">
                    <label class="radio-label" for="s_method_premium"><span class="radio"></span> <span class="method-title"><span class=
                    "price"><span class="currency">£</span>39</span>Take it to my room</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

To do this using jQuery, here's the code snippet:

```js
$('#s_method_premium').attr('checked', 'true');
```

The basic explanation is that you are using the `attr` method of jQuery to modify the property (i.e., the first argument) with the desired value (i.e., the second argument). And then necessity for both lines of code is to remove the first checked before setting the second one.

Does that help?

Comment: is it possible to move the "checked" using the jQuery code?

Comment: If I paste the code as it is would that trigger on mobile devices by default as well?

Comment: @BenCodeZen No need to set the previously checked radio button to false.

Comment: When I apply the code it come up with error: "VM980:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of null"

Comment: @John Where are you calling the script? If it is being loaded before the document is ready, that could be a reason you are getting a 'null' on the selector.